# How to obtain the value of a specific property in DataRow (unknown) object using LINQ / Reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach, properties

How can I obtain a specific row in RowData property of my variable? I'm trying to obtain "Id". What I've tried so far is either LINQ or just a regular foreach loop, however I'm only able to acces GetType().GetProperties(). From these methods I'm unable to acces the value of "Id".

[image]

What I've tried so far:

I've tried using reflection like this:

```
public void CommandClickHandler(CommandClickEventArgs<object> args)
{
    TabObj.Select(2);
    var IdOfModel = args.RowData.GetType().GetProperties().Single(pi => pi.Name == "Id").GetValue(args, null);
}
```

But this is giving me the error "Object does not match target Type".

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: test.RowData.Id ?..

Comment: *test.RowData.Id* @RomanRyzhiy he prolly can't as RowData's type is prolly `object` ...

Comment: Thats correct, if i use test.RowData.Id I'm getting the following: GetType(), ToString(). GetHashCode()

Comment: instead using `Grid<object>` use `Grid<YourTypeProllyUser>` then youll be able to use it like Roman wrote (as then `CommandClickEventArgs<object>` will became `CommandClickEventArgs<YourTypeProllyUser>` , i guess but it should be stated in docs)

Comment: I cant do that since the page is dynamically build. It must be possible to acces to value of Id somehow right?

Comment: then make you all types using Grid implement interface `IEntityWithId` ... so you can use `Grid<IEntityWithId>` ...

Comment: Isnt there a simpler way? I mean i acces see values already in debugger

Comment: *Isnt there a simpler way?* yes, change language from C# to the one which is not type-safe

Comment: I see examples they use reflection like this: args.RowData.GetType().GetProperties().Single(pi => pi.Name == "Id").GetValue(args, null); But this is giving me error: object does not match target type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear what's going on if you break that up.  You're passing the wrong argument to `PropertyInfo.GetValue(object,arg[])`, and it should be:

```
var obj = args.RowData;
var type = obj.GetType();
var IdOfModel = type.GetProperties().Single(pi => pi.Name == "Id").GetValue(obj, null);
```

or simply

```
dynamic obj = args.RowData;
var IdOfModel = obj.Id;
```